# Progress Dialog does not appear

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a fragment that, when is pressed a button should show a Progress Dialog and execute a method that contains an AsyncTask but when I press the button, the Progess Dialog does not appear on the screen but the async task is executed. This is the code of the fragment

```
public class ParcheggiaFragment extends Fragment {

private Button button;
ProgressDialog progressDialog1;
SharedPreferences prefs;
HttpGetNoleggio httpGetNoleggio;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parcheggia, container, false);

    button = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button);
    prefs = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Keys.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            progressDialog1.show();

            int a = checkNoleggioCompletato();

            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_principale, new ResultFragment());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

        }
    });

    return layout;
}

private int checkNoleggioCompletato() {

    final int id = prefs.getInt(Keys.ID_UTENTE, -1);

    Integer[] noleggio;
    int idNoleggio = -1;
    try {
        String str = "here i put the url that i have to use" + id; 
        URL url = new URL(str);

        noleggio = httpGetNoleggio.execute(url).get();
        idNoleggio = noleggio[0];
        int idBici = noleggio[1];
        int noleggioResult = idNoleggio;
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return idNoleggio;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {

    progressDialog1 = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());
    progressDialog1.setIndeterminate(true);

    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    httpGetNoleggio = new HttpGetNoleggio(this.getActivity());

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

}

The code seems correct and I can't understand why the ProgressDialog does not appear. 
`HttpNoleggio` is another class that extends AsyncTask and implements the doInBackground method

Comment: Where are you removing the dialog. It may be possible that task completes so quickly that the dialog doesn't even gets time to show up.

Comment: @Shaishav the task takes 7second to complete. The ProgressDialog doesn't appear in this fragment but appears in the next Fragment `ResultFragment`

Comment: I don't understand, you said *"the Progess Dialog does not appear on the screen"*. Aren't you starting the `ResultFragment` on button click only?

Comment: @Shaishav I forgot to say that the ProgressDialog appear when the fragment is Changed. In this case, it appears when ResultFragment appears on the screen

Comment: Again, you said *"execute a method that contains an AsyncTask"*. Where is this `AsyncTask`? The new fragment should start up immediately (as you start a new transaction) and above that the progress bar should appear. Is this not what you intend to do? If not, why are you starting the transaction?

Comment: in `checkNoleggioCompletato` there is `HttpGetNoleggio`, another class that extends AsyncTask. I want ProgressDialog shown while `checkNoleggioCompletato` is completing

Comment: Then get rid of that fragment transaction on the button click and put it inside `onPostExecute` of your `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you are displaying the progress bar in ParcheggiaFragment and then replacing this fragment with ResultFragment. As ResultFragment replaced ParcheggiaFragment so that progress bar is not displaying. Just comment the following code:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_principale, new ResultFragment());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Then, progressbar will be visible.

Comment: But, he is initialising the progress dialog with activity's context so, shouldn't it appear (and behave legitimately) no matter what `fragment` is displayed?

Comment: ProgressDialog appear when the fragment is Changed. In this case, it appears when ResultFragment appears on the screen

Comment: As per the code progressbar is visible but above this new ResultFragment appear because of new transaction.